# Using wildcard search and replace in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Basically I have the following in Notepad++:

```
|RD1-team01=
|RD1-team02=
|RD1-team03=
|RD1-team04=
```

... and so on. And I want to use the wildcard to add a space before the equals sign (=). There are numerous other equals signs in the document, so I cannot use find and replace.  How can I do this in Notepad++?

Comment: Please clarify how the equals signs that you want to affect are distinguished from those that you don't want to affect.  Is it ones at the ends of lines?  Ones after a number?  Ones after `RD1-team<digit><digit>`?

Comment: I was successful in testing a search and replace all: searched "=" and replaced with " =". There's a button labeled "replace all". I should note I'm using 6.7.5. Are there additional patterns to your existing equal signs?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression.

Follow these steps on notepad++:

1. Ctrl+f
2. click on '`replace`' tab
3. on 'find what' the following: `^\|RD1\-team(..)\=`
4. on '`replace with`' enter the following: `\|RD1\-team$1 \=`
5. on the '`search mode`' box on the lower left corner be sure to select '`Regular Expression`' AND uncheck '`. matches new line`'
6. finally click '`replace all`'

Note: this specific regular expression (regex) will look for the first occurrence of "`|RD1-teamXX=`" in a line and only add the space to that specific segment.

For example this line:

```
|RD1-team04=|RD1-team01=test
```

became:

```
|RD1-team04 =|RD1-team01=test
```